# i want create dropdown submenu in my wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, submenu, dropdown

i create a wordpress theme (convert HTML to wordpress), but i don't know how i create a dropdown submenu.
i used this code in header.php :

```
<div id="mainmenu">
                <?php wp_nav_menu(['theme_location' => 'our-custom-

menu',]); ?>
</div>
```

and i use this codes in style.css :

```
 #mainmenu ul{
    float:right;
    width:50%;
    height:62%;
    margin-right:20%;
    margin-top:0px;
    color:#44006f;
}

#mainmenu li{
    float:right;
    margin-right:1px;
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:43px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    color:#000;
    font-family:NeoSansArabic, arial;
}

#mainmenu li:hover{
    color:#fff;
}

#mainmenu li a{
    color:#000;
}

#mainmenu li a:hover{
    color:#F172C3;
}
```

and i use this code in function.php :

```
add_action('init', function() {
    register_nav_menu('our-custom-menu', 'main menu');
});
```

i want understand me how i create a dropdown submenu step by step, please ..

Comment: you can set submenu in wordpress admin panel by drag and drop

Comment: i do this, but a submenu is appear show always  (i mean: i want hide/show submenu by move mose pointer)

Comment: you should write css for sub menus

Comment: By default you have to hide submenus. and write css like .submenu>li:hover{display:block;}

Comment: can you help me to write a submenu code in header.php (without css codes). you can edit on my codes in above

Comment: you should write css for submenu. you cannot achive by css

Comment: can you post your header.php file and css?

Comment: you can use twentyfourteen default wordpress theme for sample.

Comment: i can write css codes, but a problem in header.php codes

Comment: can you post your header.php file and css? so i can try